# GRPC mutual authentication

Tags: grpc, micronaut, mutual-authentication

Could someone tell me how to configure GRPC mutual authentication in micronaut. All the examples I've found so far refer only to a pure grpc server in java.

At the moment I have this config:

```yaml
grpc:
  server:
    port: 8081
    ssl:
      certChain: classpath:server-cert.pem
      privateKey: classpath:server-key.pem
```

But when I test this solution with Kreya, all I have to do is disable certificate validation and I can make requests. I would like the server to force the clients to provide the correct certificate.